# Which Stock Firmware for Galaxy S3

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, device-firmware

I'm in a situation where the Galaxy S3 I have is not connecting to Wifi (bug from Android 4.1). I would like to flash a new firmware. I am  just confused on which one to use. Can I use any stock firmware as long as it has been made for the GT-I9300 or should I find one which is specific to the region of my phone?

If so, how can I detect the region of the phone?

Phone is unlocked and International version.

Comment: Related [where can i find a stock or custom ROM for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device?s=4|0.4154)

Comment: Not marked as duplicate since OP is seeking region clarification , which is specific to Samsung devices

Answer (score 1):

- You should use the latest firmware pertaining to *your region and model only*
- Authentic source for all Samsung firmware is [Sammobile](http://www.sammobile.com/). You will need to register(free) to download. If you want a faster download, there is a paid option. Make sure you select the right region
- For detailed information on Samsung devices (including region as asked) [Phone Info Samsung](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.vndnguyen.phoneinfo) is highly recommended. Developer of this app has an [active thread at XDA](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=49394347)